# Node cannot generate JWT

Tags: node.js, mongoose, jwt

I am using the `jsonwebtoken` package to generate a jwt token.

Here is my user model

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }
})
```

Here is a user schema method to generate a token for each user:

```
userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = () => { 
  var token = jwt.sign({ _id: this._id}, 'shhhhh');
  return token
}
```

However when running this piece of code to verify the token, when logging the payload, I get `undefined` logged instead of the payload. Does Anybody know why?

```
jwt.verify(token, 'shhhhh', function(err, decoded) {
    if (err) console.log(err)
    console.log(decoded._id) // bar
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the function jwt.sign you must set a time to expiration.

Here is an example:

```
exports.logEmployee = (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({ token: 'Bearer ' + jwt.sign(req.employee, process.env.SECRET, { expiresIn: 1800 }) });//expires in 1800 seconds
    res.end();
};
```

I believe in your case, the `expiresIn` variable is being set as a value very close to zero. So its generated and at same time being invalid by the time passed between generation and validation.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `arrow` functions ,use `normal` function for your schema methods

```
userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function() { 
  var token = jwt.sign({ _id: this._id}, 'shhhhh');
  return token
}
```

As per docs

> Do not declare methods using ES6 arrow functions (=>). Arrow functions
> explicitly prevent binding this, so your method will not have access
> to the document and the above examples will not work.

Link [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods)

Because of the reason stated above your `this._id` doesn't gets set ,so its always `undefined` ,when you try to verify it